# Convex Combination Meaning

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming

I studied the formal definition of a convex combination ( the one considering **more** than 2 points) , but i have not understood the intuitive meaning of it.
Could you explain me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's look at first at the definition:

> Given a vectro space $X$ and points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in X$, we call convex combination every other point $x\in X$ such that:
> $$x=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i$$
> where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n\geq0$ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=1$.

So, intuitively, it is like every convex combination of the points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ is created like: we tak "some" of $x_1$ and "some" of $x_2$ etc, up to $x_{n-1}$ and the rest (if) needed, is taken from $x_n$. Now, let's have a look at an example - we will stay at a very intuitive level, formal proofs are not difficult, but they require a lot of calculations.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $A,B,C,D,E$ be the following points on the plane:
[image]

Now, a convex combination of these five points can be any point that belongs in the minimum convex set that contains all of these points - this is called "convex hull" of the points $A,B,C,D,E$. But which is this set?

Well, this is a convex set that contains all of the points, but one could do better than this with not that much effort:
[image]

If we elaborate a little bit on this, we can see that, a way to find this set is as follows:

- Find the point that is "lower" than any other (the smallest $y$-coordinate). In our case this is $C$.
- Pin a rope onto this point and start moving this rope around the plane counterclockwise starting from a horizontal position, until you meet $C$ again. If one can think of the other points as "pegs", then the following shape occurs:
  [image]

Now, every point into this shape - or its boundary - is a convex combination of $A,B,C,D,E$. Actually, since $E$ is in the inner part of the convex hull, it is a convex combination of $A,B,C,D$, so, these four points are sufficient to generate this shape - our rope did not meet the $E$ "peg" while rotating. A step further, one can show that for every $x$ in the convex hull described, we can find $3$ of $A,B,C,D$ such that $x$ is a convex comabination of them (these three points will form a triangle that includes the point $x$, from wichi it is also implied that the tringle is the elementary shape of the Eucledian plane):
[image]

**Note:** If we let $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$ with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=1$, we can get every point on the plane that these points create - in our case this is the same as $\mathbb{R}^2$. This kind of combination is called an "affine" combination of $A,B,C,D,E$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to say that a positive combination of some vectors generate a convex cone ?

Comment: Could you define positive combination? Meaning $\lambda_i>0$ and no condition about their sum, no, it is not, since, taking, for instance $C,D$, with $$\lambda_1 C+\lambda_2 D$$ you can either "create" the entire plane - if $C,D$ are linearly independent or the line $C$, if not.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος $C=(1,0)$, $D=(0,1)$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.. Could you explain how $\lambda_1C+\lambda_2D,\ \ \lambda_1, \lambda_2 > 0$ can generate the entire plane and so for example the point $B=(-1, -1)$?

Comment: Yeap, you're, I wrote $\lambda_i>0$ but I had in my mind that they were just real numbers. So, I re-state, my claim, you can generate one "half" of the plane. Sorry for the misconception.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος with (1,0), (0,1) and $\lambda_i >0$ you can generate at most one "quarter" of the plane. If you take $\lambda_i \geq 0$ you will get the whole quarter delimited by the extreme rays $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. This is a cone, more precisely a pointed cone, since it has a vertex in (0,0).

Comment: Yeap, you're (again) right, I now see it clearly!